# SSIS comma replace in text file

Tags: ssis, bids

I m working with SSIS

I have created a package to modify a file named "abc.txt"

```
1 , 89
2 , 90
```

Now , I want to modify in SSIS itself new named "abc_new.txt"

```
1 + 89
2 + 90
```

Any comments on this , would be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flat File Source -> Derived Column -> Flat File Destination

Read the data in using a flat file source (CSV). Make all your column data types as string in the connection manager.

In the derived column editor, create a new output column `output` and use a formula like `[Column1] + "+" + [Column2]`

Write to a flat file output.